# How partitions in azure event hub and partition by keyword in azure stream analytics is related?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-parallelization#calculate-the-maximum-streaming-units-of-a-job

As per the documentation,
Eg.

Query

*The input data stream is partitioned by 16.

*The query contains one step.

*The step is partitioned.

Max `SUs` for the job

```
96 (6 * 16 partitions)
```

What is that means?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

To understand the example in the document, kindly understand "How many streaming Units are required for a specific job".

- If a step don't contain "**PARTITION BY**", then maximum of **6 SUs** for the
  job.
- If a step contain "**PARTITION BY [N]**", then maximum of **6 * [N]
  SUs** for the job.

[image]

> How many Streaming Units are required for a job?

Choosing the number of required SUs for a particular job depends on the partition configuration for the inputs and the query that's defined within the job. The Scale page allows you to set the right number of SUs. It is a best practice to allocate more SUs than needed. The Stream Analytics processing engine optimizes for latency and throughput at the cost of allocating additional memory.

In general, the best practice is to start with **6 SUs** for queries that don't use **PARTITION BY**. Then determine the sweet spot by using a trial and error method in which you modify the number of SUs after you pass representative amounts of data and examine the SU% Utilization metric. The maximum number of streaming units that can be used by a Stream Analytics job depends on the number of steps in the query defined for the job and the number of partitions in each step.

Hope this helps.